# ST3 Synthax Error with TeXLive

Tags: latex, sublimetext3, ubuntu-16.04

Yesterday I came across [this syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcU13.png) and I have absolutely no explanation for it. This is a template (https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) that works perfectly on Texmaker.

Am I missing something very obvious? 
I'm using ST3 Build 3176 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The syntax error is not very long. Your question would be more useful (easier to read, find by searching, etc.) were you to enter the error directly into the text (rather than including a screenshot).

Comment: Are you sure that the build system selected knows about Latex? That looks exactly like what the `python` command would say if you told it to execute that script.

Comment: @OdatNurd It was exactly that. I'm an idiot. ST3 identified the syntax as LaTeX so I didn't even remember to check the build system.